# Nested categorical variables as aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have a dataset where I have a categorical variable where the categories are of two different fundamental types: for instance, that one of them represents the total of the values from the other two categories.  I can encode this by a separate categorical variable, say `is_total`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~categorical, ~is_total,
   0,  0,          "A",     FALSE,
   1,  1,          "A",     FALSE,
   0,  1,          "B",     FALSE,
   1,  3,          "B",     FALSE,
   0,  1,      "Total",      TRUE,
   1,  4,      "Total",      TRUE
)
```

I then want to create a line plot, where the total is shown with one type of line and the two components are shown with another type of line, and all three lines have different colours.  I can do that like this:

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, colour = categorical, linetype = is_total)) +
  geom_line()
```

The problem is that I don't want two legends: I want "Total" to be shown with a dashed line in the second legend (and then I can get rid of the legend for `is_total` using `guides(linetype = FALSE)`).  How would I do that?  (I hoped changing the titles to be the same using `labs` would make it work things out, but sadly not.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to map `categorical` on `linetype` too and set your desired linotypes via `scale_linetype_manual`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~categorical, ~is_total,
  0,  0,          "A",     FALSE,
  1,  1,          "A",     FALSE,
  0,  1,          "B",     FALSE,
  1,  3,          "B",     FALSE,
  0,  1,      "Total",      TRUE,
  1,  4,      "Total",      TRUE
)

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, colour = categorical, linetype = categorical)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(A = "solid", B = "solid", Total = "dashed"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I think that's probably the best way of doing it.  (I can't upvote because I don't have enough reputation yet, but I will come back and upvote when I do!)